# All controls of MDI form showing in front of child form in c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, mdi

Panel control of MDI form showing in front of child form.........

```
private void contentsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
            foreach (Form frm in fc)
            {
                if (frm.Name.ToLower() == "frmshortcutkeys")
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            frmShortcutKeys objfrmShortcutKeys = new frmShortcutKeys();
            objfrmShortcutKeys.MdiParent = this;
            objfrmShortcutKeys.Show();
        }
```

Comment: its not working plz tell me other soln

Comment: i also did  panel.SendToBack(); but its not working. plz tell me other soln.

Comment: MDI child windows are parented to the MDI client window, the dark grey window in the parent.  Any controls you put on the parent will always be in front of it, overlapping the MDI children.  You must dock the panel to an edge.  That shrinks the MDI client window.

Comment: Ah - I was getting it to work using a DataGridView not a panel.  It must be because the panel is a container control?